# Python script to apply same command to each file in a folder

Tags: python, regex

Ideally, I would like to create a Python script to apply the same RegEx command to all individual files in a particular folder - this script would apply the command to an input file and then save the file to the same folder, just with a different extension (i.e., `.txt` instead of `.tt`).

Let's say that I have a FOLDER with 5 different files:

```
FOLDER1
    File1.tt
    File2.tt
    File3.tt
    File4.tt
    File5.tt
```

I would like to use the following command to covert the .tt files to .txt files

```
awk '{print $1"_"$2}' < File1.tt | tr -s "\n" " " > File1.txt
```

However, I do not want to apply this command individually to each file. Rather, I would like to create a Python script that will allow me to apply this command to each file within the folder.

Comment: Why do you want python? why not a simple bash script? `for f in *; do awk '{print $1"_"$2}' < "$f" | tr -s "\n" " " > "${f/.tt/.txt}"; done`

Comment: "I would like to create a Python script...."    What's stopping you?

Comment: Any Update with the script?

Answer (score 0):

What about using `endswith` and `shutil` with `os.walk`as below-
This script wil find all files that have `.tt` extension (by `endswith`) in the folder `C:\Users\fldr` and if corresponding `.txt` file is not existed then it will create corresponding `.txt` file and copy the content of `.tt` into `.txt` file in that folder i.e. `C:\Users\fldr`

```
import os,shutil

folder = r"C:\Users\fldr"
for root, dir, files in os.walk(folder):
    for single_file in files:
        if single_file.endswith('.tt'):
            base, extension = os.path.splitext(single_file)
            old_file_path = os.path.join(root,single_file)
            new_file_path = os.path.join(folder,base+'.txt')
            while not os.path.exists(new_file_path):
                shutil.copy(old_file_path, new_file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive, little painless approach, lots of code, but readable and maintainable. Just place this script outside the directory your want to operate on.

```
import os

myfiles_directory = "testing"

def files_in_dir(dirname):
    """
    Given a valid directory it will do the listing of files inside that directory
    @param: dirname --> Directory where your files are residing.
    """
    if(os.path.isdir(dirname)):
        return os.listdir(dirname)


def full_filepath(filename, directory):
    """
    Given a filename and a directory, construct the full file path,
    tracking our current working directory.
    @param: filename --> File we want to make full path of.
    @param: directory --> The directory to make path against the file.
    """
    if(isinstance(filename, list)):
        for files in filename:
            yield os.path.join(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), directory), files)


def write_rename_file(fullfilepath, current_prefix="tt"):
    """
    For simplicity we shall open the file and write it with a new name
    based on the other name.
    @param: fullfilepath --> The whole file path we want to operate on.
    @param: current_prefix --> The prefix we want to get rid of, replacing with txt.
    """
    if(fullfilepath.endswith(".txt")):
        pass 
    else:
        open_current_file = open(fullfilepath, "r")
        open_new = fullfilepath[:-len(current_prefix):] + "txt"

        # Preventing creating new file again
        if(os.path.exists(open_new)):
            pass 
        else: 
            open_new_file = open(open_new, "w")
            open_new_file.write(open_current_file.read())
            open_new_file.close()
            os.remove(fullfilepath)

fileslist = files_in_dir(myfiles_directory)

for f in  full_filepath(fileslist, myfiles_directory):
    print write_rename_file(f)
```

I hope this works for you, take your time and understand what the script,does
try to modify it and suite your needs.
Remember that the file is finally deleted